# How to convert value_count result to new data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some of the value count results show as follows the format:

```
1    5
0    2
Name: result, dtype: int64
```

The following is part of the output:

```
000006.txt 1    2
0    1

000008.txt 1    5

000010.txt 1    4
0    3

000016.txt 1    3

000021.txt 1    3
0    2

000025.txt 1    3
0    1

000031.txt 1    3

000032.txt 1    3
0    2
```

which here means: for the result, there are 5 results =1, and 2 results =0

I understand the type of value count is series, and I try to convert the series to data frame and pivot it, but the output format is different as what I want.

```
result = data_result.to_frame('counts') # convert to frame
res = pd.pivot_table(result, columns = 'counts', values='values') # pivot dataframe
```

I need the result as:

```
            1    0   # this means the columns name is 1 and 0
000006.txt  2    1   # this line means the value count result for 1 and 0
000008.txt  5      
000010.txt  4    3      .........
```

Comment: For loop append ?

Comment: Can you add `filename2` data to your Series data?

Comment: I show more example, hopefully more clearly this time.